# Adjusting padding to fit

Tags: html, css

I'm having a real hard time trying to figure out how to fix this css issue. I'm trying to fix what's in the 3rd table content that is the compose new pm message form so that it doens't have any space between the form and the outer content just like it is on the template that says Form with Alternative Style in the form heading. I can't fix the content class rule because that completely messes up the rest of the page and you can see that if you go back to one of the other two tabs.

Template: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/forms.html

My Page JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MtzqR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent element has left and right padding and the child divs are using negative margins to compensate (not ideal but it works). Applying the same negative margins seems to work:

```
.box .content2.no-padding {
    margin: 0 -11px; /* Apply -11px margins to left and right sides */
}
```

Comment: Is it me or is the footer of the box that holds the submit and reset buttons seem to have a thicker border on the left and right side as well as the bottom of the header when I apply this which works great by the way. The js fiddle shows that.

Comment: `.actions` has a border on it which is doubling it up.

Comment: It looks odd when I click submit message to test the validation out and the yellow error message should be expanded to fit.

Comment: I'm just trying to have a nice decent looking form but for some reason it's not looking great with some of the thickness around parts of the areas.

Comment: The root of the problem has been fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/MtzqR/2/

Comment: Yes however on my inbox and sent tables it has no bottom border now and on the form its shifted over but thank you for helping me work through this.

Comment: Final stab at this: http://jsfiddle.net/MtzqR/5/ Good luck!

Comment: I personally think that looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try and set the following:

```css
.box .content2,
ul.block-list {
    margin: 0;
}
```